# Flutter post-install hook of the Podfile error

Tags: ios, ruby, flutter, cocoapods

I created a new flutter project from scratch, added the necessary packages to the pubspec.yaml file and ran the flutter pub get and then pod install command, but I get this error. I get this error both in my old projects and in my new projects.

```
An error occurred while processing the post-install hook of the Podfile.
 
undefined local variable or method `config' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x00007fb1da9d7bd0>
 
/Users/m/Documents/MobileProjects/projectOne/ios/Podfile:43:in `block (3 levels) in from_ruby'
/Users/m/Documents/MobileProjects/projectOne/ios/Podfile:41:in `each'
/Users/m/Documents/MobileProjects/projectOne/ios/Podfile:41:in `block (2 levels) in from_ruby'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:196:in `post_install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:1013:in `run_podfile_post_install_hook'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:1001:in `block in run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:149:in `message'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:1000:in `run_podfile_post_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:337:in `block (2 levels) in create_and_save_projects'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/xcode/pods_project_generator/pods_project_writer.rb:61:in `write!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:336:in `block in create_and_save_projects'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:315:in `create_and_save_projects'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:307:in `generate_pods_project'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:183:in `integrate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:170:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

My podfile is like this.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
 
# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
 
project 'Runner', {
'Debug' => :debug,
'Profile' => :release,
'Release' => :release,
}
 
def flutter_root
generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
end
 
File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
return matches[1].strip if matches
end
raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end
 
require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)
 
flutter_ios_podfile_setup
 
target 'Runner' do
use_frameworks!
use_modular_headers!
 
flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
target 'RunnerTests' do
inherit! :search_paths
end
end
 
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
end
end
 
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
end
```

Also, no matter what I do, Pods_Runner is colored red in Xcode and cannot be found.